# Google Maps touch screen not work using Intel XDK

Tags: cordova, google-maps, intel-xdk

I have a problem using Google Maps on Intel XDK is that the similarlo and compile it does not work touch on the map, I searched for several sides and can not find that may be due.

To load the map use the following code:

function.js

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#pageone', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        initMaps();
    },500);
});
```

loadMaps.js

```
var map;
function initMaps() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
        center: {lat: -32.887477, lng: -68.861384},
        zoom: 10,
        draggable: true,
        disableDefaultUI: true
});

function cargarMapas() {
    returnCoords();
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function(){
          document.getElementById('googleMap').style.position = 'static';
          document.getElementById('googleMap').style.background = 'none';
    });
}
```

And this use in HTML:

```
<div id="googleMaps">
   <div id="googleMap"></div>
</div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback="></script>
```

The truth've tried everything and can not be the error. I tried the example of geolocation Intel XDK but neither worked.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "not working". What is it doing/not doing that you either expect or don't expect it to?

Comment: Load the entire map and even markers but when I try to browse the map, zoom or give him click bookmarks does not work.